# How to set facebook uri redirect for oauth and homepage

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

I'm having a little problem when facebook redirect to my homepage from facebook page and from facebook oauth

For example, when I set the callback url in facebook application to be http://www.company.com/oauth/callback when user authorize my application everything works fine.

But when my app posted something on user's wall it shows the app icon nicely "http://www.company.com" However, when someone clicks on that icon it goes to http://www.company.com/oauth/callback" which causes error on my website because that redirect url doesn't have "code" parameter. How do I separate the callback url and application homepage in facebook?

Thanks a lot.